# ElasticSearch 5.2.2 having duplicate with same ID and same type - how that's possible?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am quite new to ElasticSearch technology, I've just discovered that I've got 2 documents where each of them have same `_id` and `_type` fields. Is that a bug? If not how do I find out what's the unique ID. I would like to document to be overriden on update. Now I've ended up with 2 different versions.

Elasticsearch response:

[image]

Comment: Each of those document is on a different shard, one has routing `7225` and the other `272`. If both documents are supposed to be the same, you should index them with the same routing value.

Comment: Thank you, this was a good starting point for myself.

Answer (score 0):

These 2 documents have different `_routing` which normally is derived from ID, however when set explicitly it's possible to have different documents with same ID.

I wasn't aware that my application sets the `routing`, I wasn't aware what actually the `routing` is. Even though I am still not sure why I should use I at least know what has happened that I've seemingly got duplicates. Thanks for help.